# How to install Elite Custom Race Plus bottle cages onto the Giant TCR frame?

Tags: road-bike, giant

I bought two Elite Custom Race Plus bottle cages for my Giant Advanced SLR frame. I have difficulties installing the vertical bottle cage, as the front derailleur mount blockes the space for the bottle cage screws...(as shown in the picture) How to fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I guess you have three options:

1. Install some kind of spacer below the bottle cage (a few thick washers would probably do it)
2. Cut away part of the bottle cage (if possible).
3. Get a bottle cage which doesn’t have this continuous stay from one hole to the other.

As for the spacers: Some mini pumps (e.g. Lezyne Road Drive) come with a bottle cage mount which would act as a spacer.

Comment: I have had success using option 2 in the past.  Just make sure that there is no interference from the protruding front derailleur mount with the bidon/bottle when done.  If you really like THAT cage, then it is worth a shot if it will not have that interference.